# MBProgressHUD armv7 error

Tags: iphone, objective-c, armv7, mbprogresshud

i'm trying to use MBProgressHUD. i added header an .m to project, imported header in class and call MBProgressHUD from an ibaction in this way:

```
-(IBAction)submitForm:(id)sender{
    MBProgressHUD *HUD = [[MBProgressHUD alloc] initWithView:self.view];
    [self.view addSubview:HUD];
    HUD.labelText = @"Connecting";
    [HUD show:YES];
}
```

when i build project it happens an error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
    "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MBProgressHUD", referenced from:
    objc-class-ref in FormViewController.o
    ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
    collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

How can i fix it? can you help me?

Comment: Looks like you are missing the `arm7` architecture for your library.  Did you compile the source code of MBProgressHUD framework yourself or did you download the `.framework` or static `.a` files without building it yourself?

Comment: i've downloaded .h e .m from https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD

Answer (score 65, accepted):

In your Xcode project, select your `MBProgressHUD.m` file in the list of files (along the left edge of the workspace) and look at the File Inspector for that file.

Make sure the checkbox is ***ON*** for your project in the "Target Membership" setting.

[image: Make sure Target Membership is selected for your .m file]

Comment: For me this checkbox was greyed out. I deleted files, and re-added them. This checkbox appears on the "add files" screen and is not greyed out there...solved my issue. thx!

Answer (score 5):

Just a guess, but check to make sure that `MBProgressHUD.m` is added to your Build Sources build phase.

Comment: +1 yes adding MBProgressHUD.m there only thing that worked for me, thx!

Answer (score 2):

This is weird error with XCode import, Delete MBProgressHUD (**Reference ONLY**) then add back to XCode.

if it doesn't work Few Extra steps.
1. Delete MBProgressHUD (**Reference ONLY**).
2. Comment the code related to MBProgressHUD.
3. Build.
4. Add MBProgressHUD to XCode.
5. Uncomment code.
6. Build.

Answer (score 0):

try to add CoreGraphics.framework