# juggernaut cocoa for iphone breaks with Apple Mach-O Linker (id) Error

Tags: iphone, cocoa, xcode4.3, juggernaut

I tried using juggernaut cocoa:

https://github.com/fpotter/juggernaut-cocoa

Added this line to my code:

```
        JuggernautClient *client = [[JuggernautClient alloc] initWithHost:@"myhost" port:1740];
    [client subscribe:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/reports/%@/new", current_unit.unit_id]];


    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(didReceiveMessage:)
                                                 name:JuggernautDidReceiveMessageNotification
                                               object:nil];
```

And i get the following errors:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_JuggernautClient", referenced from:
objc-class-ref in MapViewController.o
  "_JuggernautDidReceiveMessageNotification", referenced from:
 -[MapViewController viewDidLoad] in MapViewController.o
 ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

thanks for response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I see this error:

```
 ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
```

that tells me JuggernautClient.m isn't being included in the collection of files that makes up your app *target*.  Go to the File Inspector for JuggernautClient.m and set it to be included in your build.

[image: It would look something like this:]

This is a slightly different image but I picked it up from [a related question's answer I also gave.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8852905/981049)