# id: Library not found for -lMBProgressHUD

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I got this error in my Xcode. "id: Library not found for -lMBProgressHUD". I googled for it. But none is talking about "lMBProgressHUD". I added "libz.dylib". But, no use.

Comment: If you're not using MBProgressHUD in your app you can remove it from the Link Binary with Libraries section under Build Phases in your project settings

Comment: You sure, you havent misspelt it?

Answer (score 1):

this is what happens when you open your project with `$ProjectName.xcodeproj` file rather than `$ProjectName.xcworkspace`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you add `MBProgressHUD` to the Build Settings of your project and this is not necessary, unless you are using `MBProgressHUD` as an external library and that not seems to be the case, just remove `MBProgressHUD` from the Build Settings.

**P.D**: If you add `libz.dylib` to check if this was the error you can also remove it from the dependencies

Comment: I removed the MBProgressHUD. But, I'm getting a new error "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MBProgressHUD", referenced from:(listing the .o files that needs this).

Comment: Through link with libraries tab

Comment: check the ``MBProgressHUD`` [github page](https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD) and add it to your project in the way they recommend, this should solve your problem

Comment: Actually the project was cool couple of hours before. I added few files to the project with manual memory dealloc function. But, My project is checked with ARP. so, I added '-fno-objc-arc' to that file. Thats making the problem.

Comment: I added MBProgressHUD files to my project. Still No use.

Comment: Actually it is showing "Library not Found for -lMBProgressHUD" instead of "MBProgressHUD"

Comment: OK, maybe the solution is in the answers to this other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8852249/mbprogresshud-armv7-error

Comment: I tried what they specified there. But, My checkbox is disabled for that MBProgressHUD.h file.

Comment: I assume that we were taking about ``MBProgressHUD`` because ``-lname`` is a parameter that Xcode send to the linker to say it that include the library named ``name`` when linking the project, is this true or I don't understand your question?

Comment: enable the checkbox and compile again